# Use JavaScript to place cursor in a Chrome text input element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cursor, textarea, textinput

I've been working on sending text to an input element in Chrome and I noticed that, unlike in IE or FF, calling *.focus()* does not put the cursor in the text area. So does anyone know of an alternative for placing the cursor on a **Chrome** input element?

Comment: I never had problems triggering `focus()` on Chrome, could you post some code?

Answer (score 2):

I have no issues either. Here is an simple HTML file I have that works in Chrome:

```
<html>
<body>

<textarea id="ta1"></textarea>
<br />
<textarea id="ta2"></textarea>
<br />
<textarea id="ta3"></textarea>

<script>
document.getElementById("ta2").focus();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Are you putting the script section above or below the textareas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some of the code I'm using:

*var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");*

event.initEvent("focus", true, true);

element.dispatchEvent(event);

Comment: Thanks guys, now it's working. Apparently calling dispatchEvent wasn't doing it, but calling .focus() directly does work!